# AutoCShow does not trig on dynamically added words?

Tags: c#, scintilla

I am currently trying to write a small "C# as script" IDE.
(editor, with in memory code compiler, and execution)

I am not unhappy with any other implementations, I just really wanted to be able to do this my self. Now everything is going well. I can write code using a winform text controller, compile it, and run it..

Today I felt like adding some sugar, so I got my hands on ScintillaNET. (.Net wrapper for Scintilla) and simply used this controller instead of my text controller. This helped alot, and keyword highlighting, is spot on.

Now for the problem:
I wanted to have some IntelliSense like feature.
I figured, Scite comes with autocompletion, so a feature for this must be inside Scintilla somewhere. I found AutoCshow, and got it working with the highlighted keywords.
The only thing I would need now was to use reflection to get a list of classes, everytime the code is succesfully compiled, and then convert this to a list of strings, and add this to the autocompletion word list..

I get the reflection part running, and succesfully gets the list of classes from the runtime code and dump it into a list of strings `knownClasses`

So finally I Did this to trig the autocompletion:

```
//do automatic keyword completion:
editor.CharAdded += AutoCompleter;
```

and somewhere else I did this:
(I know it can be optimized, but that is not the issue here)

```
 public void AutoCompleter(object sender, ScintillaNET.CharAddedEventArgs e)
 {
        var currentPos = editor.CurrentPosition;
        var wordStartPos = editor.WordStartPosition(currentPos, true);

        // Display the autocompletion list
        var lenEntered = currentPos - wordStartPos;
        if (lenEntered > 0)
        {
            List<string> AutoCompleteList = new List<string>();
            AutoCompleteList.AddRange(ReservedKeywords);
            //AutoCompleteList.AddRange(ReservedMagicKeywords); //we should never autocomplete theese
            AutoCompleteList.AddRange(ReservedTypeKeywords);
            AutoCompleteList.AddRange(knownClasses);
            AutoCompleteList.Sort();
            AutoCompleteList = AutoCompleteList.Distinct().ToList();

            string AutoCompleteString = String.Join(" ", AutoCompleteList.ToArray());
            editor.AutoCShow(lenEntered, AutoCompleteString);
        }
}
```

For some reason this works as intended for all the `ReservedKeywords` and `ReservedTypeKeywords` but not completely for the `knownClasses`

The words from `knownClasses` *is* included in the autocompletion window, so you can scroll and see them, but the autocompletion window is not trigged if I start typing any of the words thats only in `knownClasses`. To trig the window I need to type something from the keywords list, like "void"

*Is there some other secret mechanism in Scintilla I need to handle if I want to dynamicly add words to the autocompletionlist?*

ps. I also do this on initialisation to get keyword colors:

```
editor.SetKeywords(0, String.Join(" ", ReservedKeywords.AddRange(ReservedMagicKeywords).AddRange(ReservedTypeKeywords).Sort()));
```

but this does not help even if I do it just before calling AutoCshow:

```
editor.SetKeywords(1, String.Join(" ", knownClasses));
```

Answer (score 0):

(if anyone ever wonders)

There is nothing more you would need to do.

In my case the problem was that the added words started with capital letters.
scintilla was by default set to search for exact cases.

setting:

```
editor.AutoCIgnoreCase = true;
```

at initialization, fixed the issue